# Android app update rejected by google play store because of REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions

Is anyone got rejected from google play because of REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission ?
[image: rejection reason]

I removed this permission from my app even removed plugin which used it but still got this rejection.
I checked all android manifest files, even all logs there is no REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. Actually, there will be some other older build which is containing REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission in the Testing(OPEN, CLOSED, INTERNAL) section that's why they are rejecting the app.

You can find such a build in the Policy Status section of the app console.
Btw, To fix this you have to suspend all such kinds of builds.

One way of doing it is, Take a fresh build and upload it to Internal Testing then promote this build to OPEN testing & after then promote it to production from the OPEN testing section.
This way it will exclude the older build and your fresh build will be approved. Added Screenshot for reference.
[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. How I can suspend old builds? Is it will effect on production as well? Which is active in play store

Comment: No No, It will not affect the existing build it will always be live until the new build gets released. Just follow the last paragraph in the answer it will work.

Answer (score 2):

It may be in some library that you are using, which cannot be controlled, so remove it by add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:node="remove"/>
```